Get subtotal when filtered
I am using the below formula to total the columns from AX4:BI. When I filter by manager, the total stays the same instead of just showing their cost. How can I make the total filter with the selected manager?
If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Value <> "Total" Then
    With .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1)
        .Formula = "=sum(r2c:r[-1]c)"
        .Columns(1).Value = ""
        .Columns(2).Value = "Total"
    End With
End If
End With

I keep getting errors or the formula doesn't work properly.

What's the object in With clause? Please share the whole Sub. What's the error number and text?

You should watch: Excel VBA Introduction/  This video is relevant Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset).  Your formula is also incorrect.   Use SUBTOTAL with option 9 to get filtered results, =SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)`
